# How to show marker

Tags: google-maps

How to show marker? if it already exists in Google map. Link with marker [http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=10&q=36.26577+-92.54324&ll=36.26577+-92.54324](http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=10&q=36.26577%20-92.54324&ll=36.26577%20-92.54324) 
and my function for initialization

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.26577, -92.54324);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var yourMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        'position': some_where.latLng,
        'map': map,
        'title': 'set map in option'
    });
```

or

```
    var yourMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        'position': some_where.latLng,
        'title': 'set map later'
    });
    yourMarker.setMap(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, what you seek can be done with the Places Api

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

There are, however, some limitations on the number of requests per hour, per user.

In short: you search a particular LatLng point for nearby places. Then you receive a json (or xml) list of places, wich in turn can be transformed (by you) into markers on your map.

Comment: ok, I understend, thank you. So if it already exists... I can't show?

Comment: By default, the map you show contains no markers. Those markers are created externally. I suppose the map shown on maps.google.com contains a number of markers created at that moment. I guess they use that same places api to create those markers, they don't exist per se.